# Is it bad to join two tables on different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it bad to join two tables on different data types, specifically a uniqueidentifier and a varchar?

```
SELECT...
From TableA A
Join TableB B
On A.UniqueIdentifier = B.Varchar
```

Comment: well, you cant do that. You need do a casting first. And then you may have a performance isssue because you wont be able to use index.

Comment: You have to define `Bad`. Would be slow, Will work. Should I change the  tables to a better design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly it is since that will incur a unnecessary casting to other type (provided, if a implicit cast is possible) per row and imagine what if you have millions of rows on which `JOIN` operation is happening.

Comment: I wouldnt say is `Bad` per se. Because If that is the only field you have to do the join go all Jordan and Just do it. But you will pay the price in performance.

Comment: I would say it is bad....now if it is the only option for joining then what is bad is the design which forces a sub-optimal query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, not sure ... may be you have never experienced that but per practice `JOIN` should happen between two compatible columns (I mean compatible types)

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange the bad is the design, but in my case I join `(id,x,y)` data from multiple sources. And `id` can be `{int, bigint}` `(x,y)` can be `{numeric, float}` So I cant fix/change customer db.